# How do I prevent excel from turning off the copy marquee

Tags: excel, clipboard, vba

Normally using excel when a user selects a range and copies it to the clipboard you would notice it activates a marquee around the source range, some people call this animation the 'marching ants' marquee. For my purposes I created a simple VBA script with keyboard shortcut Ctrl-T which takes that clipboard range and special-pastes it's value and format into a newly selected destination range. (Skipping it's memo and such properties I don't need pasted to the new range).

The problem arises if I want to add to the VBA script and have it also right justify the destination range text. The problem is after I add the code to right justify, it then turns off the marquee and disables the clipboard contents of the source range for any future Ctrl-T (my macro) hotkey presses into more destination ranges.  If I don't add the extra code at the end of the VBA then I can keep on pasting the source range into many destination ranges all over the spreadsheet without having to re-select the original source range/cell which I want pasted all over the spreadsheet.

The simple solution is to just re-select and copy the destination range into the clipboard but that isn't going to work since the source selection in my case is a single cell and the destination cells will be all different ranges.

Here is the code in question:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
End With
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Good question - I can provide a quick workaround if you include the line that copies the cell

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If the question is how I copy the cell, then the answer to that question is that I used the standard Ctrl-C default hotkey before I came up with another idea. This is why the answer I typed in below uses a technique to create my own "Cell copy" procedure.  Does that make sense? If not explain because I did leave all the original code I had in my spreadsheet above in my question. Thanks

Comment: I was just going to suggest to perform the Right alignment of the copied cell, **before** copying it: `SourceCell.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight`, then copy and paste it with the format (`.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats`)

Answer (score 0):

OK I didn't think I would get the answer so quickly since someone noted that Excel doesn't allow you a way to get the original range coordinates. Yes I believe that was true which is sad that we can't do something so easy but as programmers we have to make due.  Here is the solution to my problem and I hope it helps others:

Simply change the default characteristics of the copy keyboard shortcut Ctrl-C and replace it with your own subroutine which does the standard copy but also saves the object to a global variable. This way our custom keyboard hotkey sequence can access it later as many times as necessary no matter if any subroutine process turns off the marquee and clears the clipboard contents.

In the same VBA module which I have both copy and paste-special SUBroutines I created 2 global variables which contain the Source & Destination objects.

Here is the working code:

```
Public SourceCell As Range
Public DestinationCell As Range
Sub MyCopy()
'
' MyCopy Macro  (Make sure to set the macro shortcut option to Ctrl-C)
'

    Set SourceCell = Selection
    Selection.Copy

End Sub

Sub MyPaste()
'
' MyPaste Macro  (Make sure to set the macro shortcut option to Ctrl-T or our choice)
'
    Set DestinationCell = Selection
    SourceCell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    DestinationCell.Select
    'You can substitute your own paste code here
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    End With
    'The two lines below are not necessary for our custom paste hotkey but It:
    '1) Recreates the marquee for standard Ctrl-V paste operations
    '2) Shows you what your original selection was in case you forgot
    SourceCell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    'Then add the following line so the screen doesn't shift back to source cell
    DestinationCell.Select
End Sub
```

So basically the above VBA module addition will allow you to use Ctrl-C to copy a range and Ctrl-T to paste just the value & format and then it will automatically right justify.  Remember that process of what you want pasted is user modifiable.

Thanks stackoverflow for letting me leave my notes...